# how to do submit on cgi form post?

Tags: java, html, post, cgi

I have a page that has Login.cgi , I need a way to call Login Button , after providing the username and password , [ Sample html code from the page ]

```
<input name="name" type="text"/>
<input name="pswd" type="password"/>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="Submit" Value="Login"/></td>
<td><input type="Reset" value="Reset"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to do automatic Login , from post method in java ,

Appreciate the help ,

Regards,

Comment: Do you mean Java or Javascript? I'm not sure how Java would relate to the question.

Comment: @duskwuff I am trying to write a code in Java to automate login and get data after the login page and the login is for dsl router page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue there was some additional parameters that needed to be included while doing post for the form , I reviewed the code and found out what are the missing parameters and my problem is solved , all good now

Regards,